# Vim: c-del in command line mode

Tags: vim

Is there a shortcut to "delete till word start boundary" in command line mode (similar to dw in normal mode)? I want to remap C-Del to it. If no, maybe there is another way to make C-Del work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some way, a bit awkward:

```
function! CtrlDel()
    let str = getcmdline()
    let pos = getcmdpos()
    let len = strlen(str)
    let i = 0
    while pos + i < len && str[pos + i] !~ "\\s"
        let i = i + 1
    endwhile
    while pos + i < len && str[pos + i] =~ "\\s"
        let i = i + 1
    endwhile
    return strpart(str, 0, pos - 1) . strpart(str, pos + i)
endfunction
cnoremap <c-del> <c-\>eCtrlDel()<cr>
```

It consists of a function that replaces whole command line and a mapping that calls that function via <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

I think `dw` already provides what you are looking for,
for “words” that are composed solely of “word characters”
(letters, digits, and underscores). 
To handle words with punctuation, use `dW` (with a capital `W`).

Comment: dw would be a nice start, but it doesn't work in command line mode.